# Could not locate javascript files in react-split-pane

Tags: javascript, reactjs, splitter

I installed react-split-pane through npm. But couldn't reference it to my project.
Please let me know how to reference this in the project.

The GitHub repo is https://github.com/tomkp/react-split-pane

Answer (score 0):

usually you have to include this line in the header of your file `import SplitPane from "react-split-pane"` so you can use the library, I'm not sure if that's your problem since you did not provide any of your code

Answer (score 0):

If you are using create-react-app then your code should look like this:

```js
//other import 
import SplitPane from 'react-split-pane'

//component declaration
export default class SomeClass extend component {
 //other logic
 render() {
 return(
    <SplitPane split="vertical" minSize={50} defaultSize={100}>
       <div></div>
       <div></div>
   </SplitPane>
 );
 
 }
 
 }
```